# TikTokApi giving me an error and I don't know why-

Tags: python, tiktok, tiktok-api

Code:

```py
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
api = TikTokApi()
for video in api.trending.videos():
    print(video.as_dict)
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\TikTok\TikTok ID Samples.py", line 3, in <module>
    for video in api.trending.videos():
  File "C:\Users\fun64\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\api\trending.py", line 40, in videos
    ttwid = spawn.cookies["ttwid"]
  File "C:\Users\fun64\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 334, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "C:\Users\fun64\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 413, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError(f"name={name!r}, domain={domain!r}, path={path!r}")
KeyError: "name='ttwid', domain=None, path=None"
```

It is the code used in the github page and youtube tutorial so it should work
https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api

Comment: code on GitHub has page [Issues](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues) where you can see if other people have the same problem. It seems it doesn't work for months.

Comment: it was working fine yesterday

Comment: @Zen35X did you manage to solve this problem?